# Steam trading issue

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive

One of my CS:GO items do not appear in the trade prompt. I've been having this issue for hours now, and I dont know what it is. In my inventory, my AK47 Redline, (the item i'm attempting to trade), and two other items appears as a blank square. I havent found an issue like this, so I'm looking for a solution. I've tried refreshing the page and restarting steam.

Thanks!

Comment: Could it be that you have recently purchased this item from the steam community market? There is a 7-day trade ban on items purchased on the market. It usually even show a message in red like "Tradable After Mar 08, 2016 (8:00:00) GMT".

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is go to your main inventory screen and preview them here.

at the bottom will be a list of tags. if the tag "not tradable" is there, you will be unable to trade this item. If this tag is on a CSGO weapon, then it means you have only obtained it recently and the 7 day trade block on this item is still active